# join multi dimensional array from multiple array in php

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

i have multiple array like this

```
$data1 = [1,2,3];
$data2 = [a,b,c];
$data3 = [x,y,z];
```

and i want to join them all into multiple array like this

```
$data = [
  1 => ['data2' => a, 'data3' => x],
  2 => ['data2' => b, 'data3' => y],
  3 => ['data2' => c, 'data3' => z]
];
```

i'm trying for loop but have no idea how to make it.

```
$data = [];
    for ($i=0; $i < count($desa); $i++) {
      $data[] .= array ($desa[$i] => [
        'info' => $info[$i],
        'link' => $link[$i],
        'sos' => $sos[$i],
        'eko' => $eko[$i]
      ]);
    }

    return $data;
```

can someone help me with this i'm using php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the key-value pair individually in the `foreach` loop.

```
// initalize the required output array
$data = [];

// loop over the data1
foreach ($data1 as $key => $value) {

  // fill the output - key from loop will be used to 
  // access the values in data2 and data3
  $data[$value] = array('data2' => $data2[$key], 
                        'data3' => $data3[$key]);
}
```

Comment: ohh tanks mate u save my day (:

Comment: @AndiHaidar happy to help :)

Comment: wait for 2 minutes to vote right answer but i'll make it thanks

Comment: seems you have a typo. Should be `$data[$value]` not `$data[value]`